# if iPhoto came with my Mac, can I still get free updates after Mountain Lion?

Tags: photos.app, mac-appstore, macos

Since:

- I got iPhoto included with my MacBook Pro, not from the Mac App Store
- Mountain Lion is replacing Software Update with the Mac App Store

Will I still be able to get free iPhoto updates with Mountain Lion?  How would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!** When you open the App Store's Updates tab, you'll see a special dialog allowing you to accept the apps such as iPhoto that were bundled with your computer. If you accept them and enter your account info, the licenses will be automatically associated with your account. In the future you'll be able to receive updates exactly as if you had purchased the apps.

(The details probably depend on which computer you have and when you purchased it. But if your computer is a relatively recent model then you probably will have access to these apps. If you want more details you may need to contact Apple.)

Comment: My Mac came with iLife and Snow Leopard. I'm currently running iLife '11 and Lion, but the App Store doesn't show me any special dialog. Does iLife have to be installed on Mountain Lion for it to show up? (My Mountain Lion is a clean install on a different partition...)

Comment: I believe machines which shipped with Snow Leopard are too old to take advantage of this (though I'm not completely sure), so you may just have to buy iLife if you want it. I suggest calling Apple to confirm.

Comment: I just got an iPhoto 9.4.1 update from the App Store, in the above-the-rest panel where OS upgrades go.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Last night I installed Mountain Lion on my 2011 iMac which came with Snow Leopard and iLife on DVD. After the install, I opened iPhoto and chose Software Update as normal.

The App Store opened and in the updates tab, it had a new section called System Updates and downloaded the updates for iPhoto and iMovie. I do not have these apps associated with my account in the App Store and thus there was a note at the bottom of the System Updates section stating that these updates are all subject to the original licence agreement.

Comment: That is correct.  The software updates are NOT going away. However, the INTERFACE is being rolled into the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't you get the iLife DVD with the MBP? or did u get the iPhoto preinstalled. If you got it preinstalled then inform Apple support before you upgrade.

Comment: The iLife suite is installed by default on new Macs. When you install Mountain Lion you don't need to notify anyone of anything, updates simply merged the old system update with app store updates, so it will update any Apple software as before, just in a unified interface.

Comment: What if he does a fresh installation Mr @AlanJC? i gave him a risk free solution.

Comment: If it's pre-installed and no media was supplied (such as on the MacBook Air or rMBP), then it will be available in the app store under the Purchases tab once you have signed in with the Apple ID used to initially set the Mac up. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: @iGameRam I'm upgrading from Lion (which was upgraded from Snow Leopard).

Comment: If you are upgrading then no worries friend, all the apps will stay intact..